# Environment issue with mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am  working with a simple **JDBC** program. While executing the program i notice the following behaviour.

The program works only when the  `mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin` file is copied in the location *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\jre\lib\ext*

I changed the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin` file to the location(*C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin*) and changed the classpath  to *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin*. But in this case the program execution fails with

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver exception
```

So my question is, Is it mandatory to copy the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin` in *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\jre\lib\ext* ?

Comment: It all depends on how you have set the `'classpath'`

Comment: `lib\ext` is deprecated and you shouldn't be using it. You simply haven't setup your classpath correctly. Please show us how you execute your program.

Comment: @RavinderReddy  I set the classpath by right click on computer> properties > advanced system settings> system properties > advaned tab > environmental variables > system variables

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes I understand that lib\ext is deprecated. But while playing with my test setup i found this. But anyway the scenario should work right?. I usually use Notepad++ to write the code and execute it using one of its plugin(not working when trying with windows command prompt also). Please see the below error  Current directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin
java FirstExample
Process started >>>
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)

Answer (score 1):

Don't put any file under the JDK installation directory. Add the jar file **itself** to the classpath, and not the directory containing the jar file:

```
java -cp c:\path\to\mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar;yourApplication.jar com.foo.bar.YourMainClass
```